# Is there a design pattern for creating type safe classes that contain arrays that can be serialised and deserialised with System.Text.JSON?

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, system.text.json

Consider a slightly contrived example:

```
   public class Polynomial
   {
      public Polynomial(int maxOrder)
      {
         MaxOrder = maxOrder;
         Coefficients = new PolynomialCoefficient[maxOrder + 1];
         for (int i = 0; i <= maxOrder; i++)
         {
            Coefficients[i] = new PolynomialCoefficient(i);
         }
      }
      public int MaxOrder { get; }
      public PolynomialCoefficient[] Coefficients { get; }
   }

   public class PolynomialCoefficient
   {
      public PolynomialCoefficient(int exponent) => Exponent = exponent;
      public double Value { get; set; }
      public int Exponent { get; }
   }
```

This might be considered "safe" in the sense that for a given polynomial order I have the correct number of coefficients that are initialised with expected `Exponent` values etc.

If serialised via the following:

```
Polynomial p = new Polynomial(3);
p.Coefficients[3].Value = 1; // p(x) = x^3
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(p, new JsonSerializerOptions() { WriteIndented = true });
```

Would produce the JSON string as follows:

```
{
  "MaxOrder": 3,
  "Coefficients": [
    {
      "Value": 0,
      "Exponent": 0
    },
    {
      "Value": 0,
      "Exponent": 1
    },
    {
      "Value": 0,
      "Exponent": 2
    },
    {
      "Value": 1,
      "Exponent": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Deserialising via the following then does not populate the `Value` in the `PolynomialCoefficient` objects.

```
Polynomial? pp = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Polynomial>(json);
```

This isn't unexpected and I could work around this, for example, by changing my `Coefficients` implementation and making it read/write.

```
   public class Polynomial
   {
      public Polynomial(int maxOrder)
      {
         MaxOrder = maxOrder;
         Coefficients = new PolynomialCoefficient[maxOrder + 1];
         for (int i = 0; i <= maxOrder; i++)
         {
            Coefficients[i] = new PolynomialCoefficient(i);
         }
      }
      public int MaxOrder { get; }
      public PolynomialCoefficient[] Coefficients { get; set; }
   }
```

Hooray, I can serialise/deserialise my class! But suddenly my implementation is no longer safe, someone could pass in an array of coefficients whose length is incompatible with the `MaxOrder` and now I've got some exception handling to do, simply to make it compatible with a specific serialising technology.

Should I sacrifice type safety in favour of "usability"?

Is there a better pattern that retains type safety but would serialise/deserialise as I am expecting?

At the moment I like the fact that it doesn't need custom JSON converters, the number of which might get out of hand quickly for a large number of small classes.

Also, I haven't decorated my code with JSON attributes. What does my polynomial care about JSON?!

Comment: Perhaps [init](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/init) will suit you?

Comment: Make a second constructor that takes `uint maxOrder, PolynomialCoefficient[] coefficients`, add all the necessary safety checks on the correctness of `coefficients` inside, and mark it with `[JsonConstructor]`.  Or add all the necessary checks in the array setter -- which can be private if you mark it with `[JsonInclude]`.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: Alternatively .NET 8 is set to support population of already initialized properties and fields, see [Support modifying already initialized properties and fields when deserializing JSON #78556](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78556).  That may/may not meet your needs depending on the details of implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few patterns available that preserve the immutability and correctness of your `Polynomial` class.

**Firstly**, you could add a second constructor that takes an nullable `PolynomialCoefficient[]? coefficients` argument and does all necessary checks on the validity of the `coefficients` array inside when non-null, and then mark the constructor with [`[JsonConstructor]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconstructorattribute?view=net-7.0).

This version of your class would look like:

```
public class Polynomial
{
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Polynomial(uint maxOrder, PolynomialCoefficient[]? coefficients)
    {
        if (coefficients != null && coefficients.Length != maxOrder + 1)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Incorrect length for {nameof(coefficients)}.  Expected {maxOrder+1}, got {coefficients.Length}.");
        MaxOrder = maxOrder;
        Coefficients = new PolynomialCoefficient[maxOrder + 1];
        // TODO: fix a possible overflow exception in this `for` statement when maxOrder > int.MaxValue  
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxOrder; i++)  
            Coefficients[i] = (coefficients != null ? coefficients[i] : null) ?? new PolynomialCoefficient(i);
    }

    public Polynomial(uint maxOrder) : this( maxOrder, null) { }

    public uint MaxOrder { get; }
    public PolynomialCoefficient[] Coefficients { get; }
}
```

Marking the second constructor with `[JsonConstructor]` causes the serializer to read the coefficient array first, then call the constructor with the array and max order already deserialized.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fRMNtl).

As a variation on this, instead of adding a second constructor, you could add a second argument to the single constructor and make it [optional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments):

```
    public Polynomial(uint maxOrder, PolynomialCoefficient[]? coefficients = default)
    {
        if (coefficients != null && coefficients.Length != maxOrder + 1)
            throw new ArgumentException($"Incorrect length for {nameof(coefficients)}.  Expected {maxOrder+1}, got {coefficients.Length}.");
        MaxOrder = maxOrder;
        Coefficients = new PolynomialCoefficient[maxOrder + 1];
        // TODO: fix a possible overflow exception in this `for` statement when maxOrder > int.MaxValue  
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxOrder; i++)  
            Coefficients[i] = (coefficients != null ? coefficients[i] : null) ?? new PolynomialCoefficient(i);
    }
```

In this case `[JsonConstructor]` is not necessary, but if you have any existing code that invokes the current constructor via reflection, it may break.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/K188nj).

**Secondly**, you could make your `Coefficients` have an explicit backing field, add a setter, and in the setter, check for correctness of the incoming array, and if correct, copy its contents over to the backing field.  The setter can be private if you mark it with [`[JsonInclude]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonincludeattribute?view=net-7.0).

This version of your class would look like:

```
    public class Polynomial
{
    public Polynomial(uint maxOrder)
    {
        this.MaxOrder = maxOrder;
        this.coefficients = new PolynomialCoefficient[maxOrder + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxOrder; i++) // TODO fix possible integer overflow
        {
            Coefficients[i] = new PolynomialCoefficient(i);
        }
    }
    public uint MaxOrder { get; }
    
    readonly PolynomialCoefficient[] coefficients;
    [JsonInclude]
    public PolynomialCoefficient[] Coefficients 
    { 
        get => coefficients;
        private set
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(coefficients);
            if (value.Length != coefficients.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Incorrect length for {nameof(value)}.  Expected {coefficients.Length}, got {value.Length}.");
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                if (value[i] == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Null coefficient at index {i}.");
            for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.Length; i++)
                coefficients[i] = value[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M1imKR).

**Finally**, as a variation on the second approach, if you don't want to annotate your classes with JSON attributes for some reason, you can make the `Coefficients` setter be public but [init-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init):

```
    readonly PolynomialCoefficient[] coefficients;
    public PolynomialCoefficient[] Coefficients 
    { 
        get => coefficients;
        init
        {
            ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(coefficients);
            if (value.Length != coefficients.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Incorrect length for {nameof(value)}.  Expected {coefficients.Length}, got {value.Length}.");
            for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++)
                if (value[i] == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException($"Null coefficient at index {i}.");
            for (int i = 0; i < coefficients.Length; i++)
                coefficients[i] = value[i];
        }
    }
```

Public `init` setters are still called by the serializer.

Demo fiddle #4 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/58AxsR).

Notes:

- You have a potential integer overflow in your constructor if the value of `uint maxOrder` happens to be greater than `int.MaxValue`, because your loop variable `i` is signed:

  ```
   for (int i = 0; i <= maxOrder; i++) // TODO fix possible integer overflow
   {
       Coefficients[i] = new PolynomialCoefficient(i);
   }
  ```

  I'm not sure why you made `maxOrder` be unsigned, but the overflow should be fixed.
- .NET 8 is set to support population of existing objects.  See *[Support modifying already initialized properties and fields when deserializing JSON #78556](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/78556)* for details.  So there may be additional patterns possible in that release.
- Annotating classes with serialization attributes is a common practice used my multiple MSFT and 3rd party serializers including `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, the obsolete `BinaryFormatter`, Json.NET and protobuf-net, so it's not clear why you would object to doing so.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for providing such a detailed response.

Comment: I have amended the example to remove the unit, so as not to confuse the question. I think perhaps your second example suits me best. I guess the caveat is that as the class grows your constructor signature grows with it, but for a large number of small classes this is pretty manageable.

Comment: @tmren - In cases like that I would recommend using factory methods to create instances of `Polynomial` when you don't need all the constructor arguments.